# How to get file size and type from S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave_direct which uploads files directly to S3.  I need to persist file info into the db - such as file type and size.  Curious what the best way to do this?

Comment: Is this info to be displayed to the user or for validation?

Comment: Info is to be displayed to the user via their account.  I need to show how many files they have and how big they are.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3910071/9225626), the optimal way for it is using *head_object* method, which does not download the content of the file itself.

[sdk-for-ruby docs:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#head_object-instance_method)
*The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested in an object's metadata. To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the object.*

So, for file_size and file_type you can:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region:               'us-east-1',     #or any other region
  access_key_id:        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secret_access_key:    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

res = s3.head_object(bucket: bucket_name, key: object_key)
file_size = res[:content_length]
file_type = res[:content_type]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with the [imagemagick identify command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php). Just before/after you save the file, you need to compute it's size. The file must be local (so if it's already on S3 you have to download it again):

```
identify the-image.jpg
#=> rose.jpg JPEG 640x480 DirectClass 87kb 0.050u 0:01
```

It will output a string that you have to parse. RMagick has an api that will give you the width/height/type automatically but I can't seem to find it (this might help: [RMagick returns nil reading JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539386/rmagick-returns-nil-reading-jpeg)).

Comment: Curious - this is for all file types - such as pdfs and docs.  Wondering if RMagic is just for images.